# Why TRUNCATE TABLE cannot use four-part name?

Tags: sql-server, truncate

I was trying to truncate a table as the following:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE [servername].[dbname].[schema].[table]
```

I  got error:

> object doesn't exist or you don't have permissions.

However, if I remove the `servername` part, it works.

Can anyone explain why I cannot use four part name in truncating? Thanks.

Comment: are you trying to use this over a linked server connection or on the local server?

Comment: nope I do it in the same server.

Comment: If it's on the same server, then why do you need the four part name? According to MSDN, it only accepts up to three part naming (database.schema.table).[link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177570.aspx)

Comment: @SQL_JGood so how can you explain that you can query the data using this way , but you cannot truncate a table using it?

Comment: This is because we are actually put a synonym after truncate table, and the synonym contains the server name. @SQL_JGood

Comment: @Joann.B - Could you use a linked server instead? Check out this [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/dbd287b1-2312-43ab-a2b9-3e75e9c267d4/truncate-a-table-from-linked-server?) on truncating a table on a linked server.

Answer (score 7):

**It's because TRUNCATE is DDL rather than DML**

From MSDN:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE 
    [ { database_name .[ schema_name ] . | schema_name . } ]
    table_name
[ ; ]
```

Also, regarding permissions:

> The minimum permission required is ALTER on table_name. TRUNCATE TABLE
>   permissions default to the table owner, members of the sysadmin fixed
>   server role, and the db_owner and db_ddladmin fixed database roles,
>   and are not transferable. However, you can incorporate the TRUNCATE
>   TABLE statement within a module, such as a stored procedure, and grant
>   appropriate permissions to the module using the EXECUTE AS clause.

Notice the db_ddladmin requirement.  As DDL, the four-part naming isn't allowed.  Compare it to Technet info on the FROM clause:

> If the table or view exists in another database on the same instance
>   of SQL Server, use a fully qualified name in the form
>   database.schema.object_name.
>
> If the table or view exists outside the instance of SQL Server, use a
>   four-part name in the form linked_server.catalog.schema.object. For
>   more information, see sp_addlinkedserver (Transact-SQL). A four-part
>   name that is constructed by using the OPENDATASOURCE function as the
>   server part of the name can also be used to specify the remote table
>   source. When OPENDATASOURCE is specified, database_name and
>   schema_name may not apply to all data sources and is subject to the
>   capabilities of the OLE DB provider that accesses the remote object.

Sources:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177570.aspx

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177634.aspx

**Edit**:
To answer your question on how to do it, write a stored procedure in the target database.  Grant access to execute the procedure, and call truncate from the procedure.

Comment: Thank you David. But how can we realize truncating a table from a linked server? I found some solution like "EXECUTE [server].master.dbo.sp_executesql N'SQL YOU WANT TO RUN'". But this means the user should have execute permission on master db, isn't it?

Comment: You can have a stored procedure in your linked procedure that calls TRUNCATE TABLE.  Then grant access to the procedure to your user account.